# fetch data from mysql and replace duplicate entry

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table name `test` with columns `id(primary key)` and `t1(varchar)`. `t1` contains the email id which have multiple duplicate entries. So i want to select all data and replace the duplicate entry a blank row for example:

### the table looks like

```
 id   |   t1
  1   |    a@gmail.com
  2   |    b@gmail.com
  3   |    c@gmail.com
  4   |    a@gmail.com
  5   |    e@gmail.com
  6   |    c@gmail.com
```

### the result i want

```
 id   |   t1
  1   |    a@gmail.com
  2   |    b@gmail.com
  3   |    c@gmail.com
  4   |    DUPLICATE
  5   |    e@gmail.com
  6   |    DUPLICATE
```

FIDDLE LINK: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e94620/2

### OR

can i get this done using PHP

Comment: So what you've tried...

Comment: i can get the duplicate entries but how to replace them. i have attached fiddle link @YashParekh

Comment: Its better to get all the data and manipulate it in PHP as per your needs.

Comment: try `DISTINCT` query in MySQL no need to do it with php and if you dont want to use `DISTINCT` then in php you can call `array_unique` on array of duplicate entries also on.

Comment: @KunalAwasthi but how to put 'duplicate' when their is duplicate value. I want to replace the duplicate value

Comment: I suspect it'll be easier in PHP. SELECT all the data from the table. Create an array to hold values you've seen before. Each time you process a row from the database, check whether it's in the array of seen-before values. If not, add it to that array and move to the next row. If it _is_ already seen, then run a SQL UPDATE to change the value in the row to DUPLICATE as per your requirement. The logic's not too hard, you can try it for yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So...

I had a look into this, and it's much easier in PHP, for example, I have the following script;

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>

<?php

$data = [ // This will be your info from DB
    1 => 'a@gmail.com',
    2 => 'b@gmail.com',
    3 => 'c@gmail.com',
    4 => 'a@gmail.com',
    5 => 'e@gmail.com',
    6 => 'c@gmail.com'
];

$used_emails = [];

foreach ($data as $key => $part)
{
    print "<tr><td>" . $key . "</td><td>";
    if (!in_array($part, $used_emails))
    {
        print $part;
        $used_emails[] = $part;
    }
    else
    {
        print "duplicate";
    }
    print "<td></tr>";
}

?>

</table>
```

And this results in;

```
ID  Email
1   a@gmail.com 
2   b@gmail.com 
3   c@gmail.com 
4   duplicate   
5   e@gmail.com 
6   duplicate
```

This gets the results, and for each, checks to see if they've been used, if not, display and say it's used, otherwise, print "duplicate"

Here is my example working; https://tehplayground.com/BKTIXja1usyRxYM3

Comment: one more question i have 2 select box from which user will select the range like user select from=10 and to=18 than it remove duplicate as your answer is working but should only print from id 10 till id 18. how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

or use SQL query:

```
select id, t_new as t1
from
(
  select id, t1,
      @num := if(@data = `t1`, @num + 1, 1) as `counter`,
      if(@num>1, 'DUPLICATE', `t1`) as t_new,
      @data := `t1` as `blabla`
  from
  `test`
  order by `t1`
) x
order by `id`
```

[Sqlfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e94620/198)

Comment: You should explain your answer for better understanding to OP. It may leads to raise up compared to other answers.